# Moveit arm show chessboard position Rviz

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 7DOF arm in moveit, which I can display in Rviz and also use for planning.
I would like to include a frame to this Rviz model to show where a chessboard is located relative to the camera mounted on the robots gripper.

I have a node which can publish the TF of the detected chessboard, but I'm not sure how to merge with the moveit configuration.

I tired to use in the chess detection node the broadcaster like:

```
br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(object_transform, ros::Time::now(), "camera_front", "calibration_grid"));
```

where `camera_front`  is part of the robot configuration in moveit, and `calibration_grid` should show the position of the board relative to the camera front frame.

When I try it Rviz throws a warning:

```
[ WARN] [1438001098.758415265]: No transform available between frame 'calibration_grid' and planning frame '/base_footprint' (Could not find a connection between 'base_footprint' and 'calibration_grid' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.)
```

Tthis is my [moveit.rviz](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OTUt567KJH0mAvSK-Q7WBPfiaXang8hZdmK-u86i1h4/edit?usp=sharing) for the arm  and the functional rviz setup for the camera solo [camera.rviz](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oBkKUwAL45Il5k1kXJnjVCLzRQh_XgQ9hmoNpzdTspw/edit?usp=sharing).

Can anyone explain how can I represent the reference frame of the chessboard relative to the arm (camera  front link on the arm)? Somehow I have to tell to Rviz that `calibration_grid` is part of the tree but it does not have to be included in the movement planning for the arm.

**UPDATE 1:**
In `RVIZ` some parts of the robot arm are in warning when I load TF, in these links is `camera_front`. The warning is:
`camera_front No transform from [camera_front] to frame [base_footprint]`. This `camera_front` is a link connected to the arm through fixed joints. It seams to be that every link in this chain has this warning massage in Rviz TF.
So, this might be the problem.
When I try to broadcast like

```
 br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(object_transform, ros::Time::now(), "base_footprint", "calibration_grid"));
```

works well but the position of the chessboard is relative to the base of the arm and not the link where the camera is placed.

**UPDAT 2:**

Some detailes about the arm configuration before an observation: I connected to the last link of the arm (via fixed joints) a `camera_back_of_box` and to this a `camera_front`, all these joints (fixed) are also part of the arm group (created in moveit assistant).
Now, if I change in `Rviz` the fixed frame to one of this links that hold the camera, than I can see the position of the chessboard, but the reference frames are shifted to the bottom of the robot in the origin of the world.

I think, this problem is due that I have multiple fixed joint is this robotic arm URDF model and if I understand well than the root of the tree should have fixed joint connection to the world. But what if there are more than one fixed joints, could this be the issue?

**Update 3:**
The `RobotState` from moveit has the transform information of all link, just have to figure out how to publish as `TF`.
Currently it seams to be two separate trees: on the base_footprint and second is the wrist_roll link. Both links have fixed joint connections. [image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214647/moveit-arm-show-chessboard-position-rviz/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-07-27**:
This should be fairly straightforward. Are you publishing the transformation from calibration_grid to base_footprint?

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-07-27**:
I'm quit new with TF so I don't realy understand your question. `camera_front` is part of the robot arm which has the base foot print and in link camera_front is the real camera. That is why I try to broadcast like above.

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-07-27**:
I checked in `Rviz` and if I add `TF` than in the **GUI** I have an other warning related to some links to my arm: `camera_front No transform from [camera_front] to frame [base_footprint]`. But this code is automatically generated by moveit setup assistant.

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-07-27**:
All the TF frames can be published by any node. just add a static_transform_publisher node to publish the transformation you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was simple, in the launch file I have to start a node to publish the `static_transform` of the base_footprint, the `joint_state`, and the `robot_state`.
It is important to publish the `joint_state` because it is needed by the `robot_state`.
The launch file script looks like:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" />
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
 <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
</node>
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen" />
<include file="$(find cyton_camera_moveit_conf)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With number of well defined (static) transforms, you should be able to represent the base-robot-camera-grid transformation chain. For debugging purposes, you could check the `TF` debugging tools, such as `view_frames` or `tf_monitor`.

---

Originally posted by [fapofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9186/fapofa/) with karma: 36 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-07-27**:
Do I have to redefine the static transformation model for the arm? Or can I use somehow the URDF model imported in MoveIt which does the hole planning for the arm? I was wondering if there could be a settings option to "turn on" the TF broadcast for some parts of the links from the URDF model.